# Looking for methods to use Jenkins to drive multithreaded Selenium testing (plugin?)

Tags: multithreading, selenium, maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

Our current Selenium project contains ~1400 test cases.  The test architecture is a Maven 3 / TestNG configuration and executes the testing with 4 concurrent threads, using the Maven Surefire plugin.

We drive this testing with an external Selenium GRID capable of up to 20 concurrent threads.

Here's the problem:  we want to cut execution time for the testing, and have found that there's little difference between 4 and 8 threads.  Higher thread counts have virtually no benefit on reducing the total execution time.

The current high level plan is to break apart the full test set into a number of smaller test sets and run them against a pool of identically configured + deployed weblogic test servers.  The GRID hub described above will still handle the Selenium Chrome clients.

My first thought is to write a maven command line for each of these test sets and execute them in the background via an '&' appended to the end of the maven line.  There will need to be a shell script loop at the end that "watches" each of these process and waits for them to finish before exiting the script.  I should be able to script this myself, but here's my question for the minds of Stack Overflow:

Rather than doing all of that in a shell script, does Jenkins have a plugin for doing something similar?  Specifically, I'd like to have Jenkins have a pool of slaves to assign the maven test sets to, 1 set per slave.  Each of these slaves would report the exit code from maven to a segment in a Jenkins pipeline corresponding to the tests that were run: e.g. - Feature_A.  This Selenium Jenkins pipeline dashboard would have instant visibility for what test sets were failing (1 or more tests failed or skipped), passing, or testing is still in progress.

I'm trying to mitigate the amount of scripting necessary, and I think the process I'm describing is generic enough that other engineers have tackled this problem abd come up with a good solution...

Here's to hoping!  Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that all your 20 grid nodes are loaded?

Comment: 4 Selenium nodes in total, configured to (by default) support 5 threads per node.